# If f is injective then there is a function $g:B\rightarrow A$ s.t. $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in A$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

If f is injective then there is a function $g:B\rightarrow A$ s.t. $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in A$

I wanted to do a proof by contradiction, but I think I did it the wrong way.

My proof is that if f is injective and there doesn't exist a function s.t. $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in A$, but then you can easily come up with a counterexample to that, but I don't know if that's a sufficient proof.

Comment: We must assume $A$ is nonempty. Your proof does not make much sense to me. You can just construct such a $g$ function.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is injective, for every $y \in B$, $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of at most one point. Fix some $a_0 \in A$ and define $g:B \rightarrow A$ to be $$
g(y):=\begin{cases} f^{-1}(y) &\mathrm{ if\ } y \in f(A) \\
a_0 &\mathrm{ if \ } x \not\in f(A) 
\end{cases}
$$

Then, for every $x \in A$, $g(f(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$, since $f^{-1}(f(x))$ consists of one point.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to create directly.  And if you understand what is being asked pretty easy.

To make a function $g: B \to A$ we must for every $y \in B$ assign a value $g(y) \in A$.  Now if $y_0$ happens to be that $y_0 =f(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in A$.  We have to assign $g(y_0) = x_0$.  Can we just do that?  Well, yes.  $f:A\to B$ is injective then if $y_0 = f(x)$ for some $x$ then there is precisely one distinct $x_0$ so that $f(x_0) = y_0$.  That's what injective *means*

So just define:  If $y \in f(A)=\{f(x)\mid x\in A\}\subset A$ then let $f(y) = x$ where $x$ is the distinct $x\in A$ so that $f(x) =y$.  This is well defined because $f$ is injective.  Had $f$ not been injective there might be $y \in f(A)$ where there are two $x,w\in A$ so that $f(x) = f(w) = y$ and we wouldn't know which one to assign $g(y)$ to.  Both $g(f(x)) = g(y) = g(f(w))  = g(y)$ but $g(y)$ couldn't equal *both* $x$ and $w$.  But that is not a problem if $f$ is injection.

Now we just have to define the values for $y \in B\setminus f(A)$.  We can assign those to anything.  Let's just say $g(y) = x_0$ for some $x_0 \in A$.

Recap:

$g(y)=x$ if there is an $x\in A$ so that $f(x)=y$.  And $g(y)=x_0$  if there is not an $x\in A$ so that $f(x) =y$.

So If $x \in A$ then $g(f(x)) = x$....